# Почему keyboard.read_key() получает русскую раскладку

Tags: python

Есть пример, который выводит какую клавишу нажал пользователь. Проблема в том, что я не понимаю как тут влияет раскладка клавиатуры и можно ли её поменять на ту, в которой сейчас печатает пользователь. Этот код работает и при английской раскладке и при русской.

```
import keyboard
if keyboard.is_pressed('q'): #Сработает и при "й" и при "q"
    rk = keyboard.read_key()
    print(rk) #Выдаёт всегда "й"
```

Как сделать так, чтобы keyboard.read_key считывала ту раскладку, в которой сейчас печатает пользователь. И как сделать то же самое для keyboard.is_pressed(). Использую библиотеку keyboarad

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос с какой библиотекой ловите нажатия

Comment: @gil9red. Добавил. Она так и называется keyboard

Comment: А попробуйте вместо `read_key` вызвать `rk = keyboard.read_event()` и у `rk` вывести поля `rk.name` и `rk.scan_code`. Проверьте какие там значения. А так, по коду https://github.com/boppreh/keyboard/blob/master/keyboard/__init__.py#L930 скорее всего выводится значение из `rk.name`

Comment: @gil9red, Похоже `read_key` действительно использует имя, но если пытаться вывести `rk.scan_code`, то не выведет ничего. Это скорее всего из-за подчерка тк `rk.name` выводит исправно. Можно это как-то поправить? Потому, что в документации написано `return event.name or event.scan_code` указываю на **or**